# Issues Updating My Android App via Play Store Internal Testing: "can't install Application"

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-console, google-play-internal-testing

I'm encountering difficulties when attempting to update my Android application through Play Store Internal Testing. Here's the scenario:

I build a new version of my app.
When the new version is ready, my build version is higher than the one installed on my device.
i add my new build to internal testing. and when i open my lower build version app.
A notification prompts me to update the app.
Upon clicking "Update," I am redirected to the Play Store.
In the Play Store, I see the "Update" option.
When I click "Update," the update process begins.
After some time, I receive an error message that says, "I can't install my app name."
I'm puzzled by this issue and would appreciate any insights into why it's happening and any common solutions to resolve it. Thank you for your assistance!

[check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgfN3.jpg)

Comment: does the app already installed in your device is installed from android studio?

Comment: Have you made sure you've turned on In-App Sharing inside the Play Store app?  I have a guide on how to do this that may come in handy for this issue: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/an-inquiry-into-androids-internal-app-sharing-a9ad2b9ae2a3?sk=b8d87ecb535a50e7b85e311638f4c03e. Lmk if it helps!

Comment: @RidhaRezzag I made one release apk, which has a lower version than my internal testing build. and I open Play Store from the old version, and then I get an update button, which does not install the beta version. But if I uninstall the apk and open the Play Store, I see only the install option, and when I install it successfully, I install the latest version.

Comment: @IvanGarza I want to test the force update feature, which needs to check versions of my apps, and according to this, it will show me the update button on the Play Store.

Comment: @noone I believe it is easier to test the force upgrade flow by having a version of your app that you installed thru App Sharing to start with, and then upgrading to yet another version (with a higher version number ofc) from the App Sharing as well.  Try it out, and steer away from building directly into your device, as Ridha recommended too.